# Swift Store Kit In app Purchase transactionState

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have make an app that uses store kit to add some character ..

I have added the `paymentQueue` function but when the pop-up is displayed and I press `Cancel`, the `transactionState` is .Completed

In this method if a user cancels the transaction he obtains the character without paying.

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
    println("add paymnet")

    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        var trans = transaction as SKPaymentTransaction


        switch trans.transactionState {

        case .Purchased:
            println("Purchase Successful")
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break;
        case .Failed:
            println("Buy Cancelled")
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break;
        default:
            println("default")
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

[This is the link of the tutorial i followed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h1gQklbrgjc)

Function tested on real device and sand box user.

Comment: `.Completed` isn't a valid member of the `SKPaymentTransactionState` enum. What do you really mean? And how do you know the customer obtains the character--are you initiating the download somewhere, or are you verifying it by looking at past purchases?

Comment: to obtain the character i set a bool value to 1 when user purchase my hero . When user visit the menu he can choose different character if the variable is != 0.

I have tested the .completed is not called if i test the procedure in the simulator and i press cancel on purchase pop up .....

Comment: I don't see anything in your code above that sets a boolean upon purchase.